# Read method return values from constructor without parameters

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

This is my superclass Masina that contains a constructor without parameters, one with parameters and a copy constructor

```
package proiect;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Masina {
    int NrDeLocuri,Putere;
    float Pret;
    String Culoare;
    String Producator;

public Masina(){
            this.Producator = "Default";
            this.Pret = 0;
            this.Culoare = "Default";
            this.Putere = 0;
            this.NrDeLocuri = 0;
            }
public Masina(String prod,int pr,String cu,int pu,int nrl)
        {
            Producator=prod;
            Pret=pr;
            Culoare=cu;
            Putere=pu;
            NrDeLocuri=nrl;
            }
public Masina(Masina other)
        {
            this.Producator=other.Producator;
            this.Pret=other.Pret;
            this.Culoare=other.Culoare;
            this.Putere=other.Putere;
            this.NrDeLocuri=other.NrDeLocuri;
            }

public Masina citireDate()
{
    Masina m=new Masina();
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduceti Producatorul : ");
    m.Producator = sc1.next();
    System.out.println("Introduceti Pretul: ");
    m.Pret = sc1.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Introduceti Culoarea: ");
    m.Culoare = sc1.next();
    System.out.println("Introduceti Puterea : ");
    m.Putere = sc1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduceti Numarul de Locuri : ");
    m.NrDeLocuri = sc1.nextInt();
    return m;

}




public String toString()
        {
            return "Producator: "+Producator+"\nPret: "+Pret+"\nCuloare: "+
                    Culoare+"\nPutere: "+Putere+"\nNumaraDeLocuri: "+NrDeLocuri;
            }
}
```

This is the test class where I create an object a of Masina's type, the data must be read with the reading method declared in Masina class named citireDate.

```
package proiect;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TestMasina {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Masina a = new Masina();

        a.citireDate();
        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }

}
```

next are the results after running the program

```
Introduceti Producatorul : 
BMW
Introduceti Pretul: 
500
Introduceti Culoarea: 
Alba
Introduceti Puterea : 
200
Introduceti Numarul de Locuri : 
5
Producator: Default
Pret: 0.0
Culoare: Default
Putere: 0
NumaraDeLocuri: 0
```

My reading method does not return the values that I gave to object's parameters like "Culoare" "Putere" etc. Return give's the default values.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you are looking for, but I would recommend by starting with making your instance variables private, and adding setters and getters for them. You may also want to read up on JUnit, if you want to write "test-classes"

Comment: `How I should write my method to return the values I give to my a object from my Masina class?` Anyone else can understand what OP is trying to ask? I read it 5 times, still doesn't understand what he wants. OP, can you rephrase your question properly?

Comment: `a.citireDate()` does return a `Masina` object . Either you need to store this one in a variable or assign the values to the `Masina` object that you are invoking it on.

Comment: You are aware of getters/setters, right?

Comment: `My reading method does not return the values that I gave ` Please show your methods.

Comment: the methods are in first code "public Masina citireDate()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in here:

```
Masina m=new Masina();
```

You are creating a **new** instance of Masina. If you want to update on the fields of your current object, you should be doing:

```
this.Producator = sc1.next();   //change m. to this.
```

Applies for the rest of the fields as well.

---

On top of that, I wonder do you understand the OO principles of using getters and setters. It looks weird to me that you are coding your logic in your class. You could set the fields as private and access them with getters and setters.

Comment: I'm not familiar with setters and getters, I'm a very beginner in Java)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't geting the expected result because function `citireDate()` return a new `Masina` object and you aren't using it you use `a` object

```
a = a.citireDate();
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

**Tip** :

1- Make instance variables private,

2-Use setters and getters to access your instance variables

3-Instead of using copy constructor use object cloning make your class `implements Cloneable`

```
public class Masina implements Cloneable{
   public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{  
     return super.clone();  
  } 
}
```

To use it :-

```
try{  
Masina a = new Masina();
Masina b = (Masina)a.clone();  
}catch(CloneNotSupportedException c){}  
  System.out.println("Not supported");
}
```

Comment: This is a bit advanced for me, I switched from C++ recently, I should read more literature about java to get known with this kind of solving my needs.. But thank you!